# Returning varchars that are not null or empty SQL

Tags: sql, varchar, isnullorempty

I have a column in SQL that is varchar. I need it to return anything with a value.

Example...

```
select * from students where StudentID <> ''
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? I've tried is not null but then it returns anything that is empty as well.

Thanks

Comment: just noticed that you say "is not null" returns empty stuff as well . . . it works for me, but maybe you have some whitespace in that field as well.  In which case you need to trim the whitespace . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using coalesce:

```
select * from students where coalesce(StudentID, '') <> ''
```

This will turn nulls into empty strings and disallow them. This has the added bonus of restricting empty strings as well.

A null is not equal to anything, not even another null, so a simple `<>` doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from students where StudentID <> '' AND StudentID IS NOT NULL
```

You can target both white space and null.

Answer (score 0):

There's something call NOT NULL

```
SELECT LastName,FirstName,Address FROM Persons WHERE Address IS NOT NULL
```

Is that helping ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

select * from students where StudentID is not null

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the case that it's not null separately because you cannot compare with null-values. They are neither equal nor unequal to any other value(incl. null). `NULL` means "unknown value", so any comparison with any actual *value* makes no sense

```
....
WHERE StudentID IS NOT NULL AND  StudentID  <> ''
```

You could use `ISNULL(StudentID,'') <> ''` (or `COALESCE`). But i think this is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ISNULL()

```
select * from student where isnull(studentid,'') <> ''
```